# Can a Database project use a machine.config connection string for deployment?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I am using a connection string for my project that is stored in the machine.config so we don't have to reconfigure each environment and each developer doesn't need to have database instances and databases named identically.

The only problem with this setup is that we use a database project and I don't see a way to configure the deployment configuration to use the same connection string. This means that for deployment purposes each developer needs to adjust the deployment project for thier environment.

Is there any way to get around this problem?

Comment: What do you mean a database project?

Comment: In Visual Studio you can create a database project and import the schema of the database so it can be managed in source control just like other source files.

Answer (score 0):

I think this pretty straight forward that each project web.config overrides machine.config settings and if not present in project .config file then it inherits so you can get advantage of it by not declaring connectionstring section in project config file as it should be present in the machine.config file and each project should be calling the name of section present in machine.config file.